How do you make an nmcli command run automatically on startup?
I have a linux mint server that I use as a media server. It reboots very infrequently, but when it does, the DNS only resolves ipv6 addresses. Something in the configuration is weird, and ping, curl and apt all fail if the url resolves to ipv4.
When I run sudo nmcli con up mediaserver the DNS will then resolve ipv4 address.
How do I set this up so that it does so automatically at boot?

A more decent approach would be investigating why is the connection down upon boot up.

Generally, to make something happen when your system boots, write a system service unit. But as @drookie says, a better solution would be to identify and resolve the underlying problem.

Thanks for the comments. Doesn't really help though, as I can't sort out what the problem is, and I don't know where to start

You start in the dmesg after booting up (before kernel buffer gets rotated), full log of your problems lies there.
